# Alternatives for safely copying objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, copy-constructor

I'm finding it very hard to find an online reference on safely copying new class objects without dealing with copy constructors. I am working on a constructor method for a child class called 'CLabel' and the professor's comments for this particular constructor's logic (this is the first of 3) is as follows:

"This constructory copies a CLabel safely to guarantee there is no memory leak."

The function header is as follows:

```
CLabel::CLabel(const CLabel& L)
```

Now taking a look at the context of the class itself, it has no explicit data members in its declaration. So my question would now be how would one make a deep copy of a class instance that is passed by reference that contains no data members.

So far here's my crack at it - it compiles, but visual studio caught an exception - "Unhandled exception at 0x770F380B (ntdll.dll) in t1.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x7710CDD8).":

```
*this = L;
 int l = L.width();
 this->_data = new char[l+1];
 int i = 0;
 for(; i < l; i++)
    ((char*)_data)[i] = ((char*)L._data)[i];
 ((char*)_data)[i] = '\0';
```

The exception got caught at this line in the tester file:

```
int mesIndx = D.add(new CLabel(7, 5, 40));
```

For as much context as you'd like on this particular assignment, the documentation for the API is at http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/The_CUI_Framework_-_OOP344_20132#CLabel

Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without seeing more of the `CLabel` code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the comment of the teacher is about the fact that if you have to create a buffer to copy the content of the CLabel, then you have to be sure it will be destroyed at the end.

ex :
if you CLabel has a member like 'char * ' and a size
You will have to make a new buffer (malloc) and not forget to delete.

Easyer solution is to design the CLabel class with a std::string member that will automatically manage the buffer and allocate deallocate memory avoiding any memory leak

Comment: **Easyer solution is to design the CLabel class with a std::string member that will automatically manage the buffer and allocate deallocate memory avoiding any memory leak**

Can you refer me as to how I can go about that?

Comment: Everything depends on what is requested for you exercise, but you can or hold and manage the string yourself as a buffer of char * that you allocate yourself and free yourself. OR if you have the right to use the standard library use std::string #include <string>. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ for use, it is a class of the std library that will hold and manage the buffer for you

Comment: I can indeed, I'm using std::str.clear() in my other methods. Thank you!

Comment: @learnenburn The important point being that if you use std::string then you don't *need* to write a copy constructor. Reading between the lines I'm not completely sure that your professor understands this. But as has already been said it would be easier if you would post your code.

Comment: Check out the link I sent in reply to Alexander's comment, it describes the entire project

Answer (score 0):

That header describes a copy constructor, so if the assignment is to implement it then you want to look at the documentation you found on copy constructors. In general, they are the right way to copy an object in C++.

As to what he means by preventing memory leaks, I'd have to know more about the assignment. The purpose of the copy constructor is often to prevent the opposite of memory leaks, double deletion/dangling pointers.

Comment: It's a group of classes that end up generating a terminal-based sort of user interface. Menus, buttons, checklists, etc.

http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/The_CIO_Framework_-_OOP344_20123#CLabel